# Springboot Restcontroller refusing to work

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have spent the last 2 hours trying to figure out just what in gods name is going on with my simple springboot rest app.

NO matter what I do, I simply cannot get the restcontroller to work, every URL I try gives me a 404. Here is my code below.

```
    @RestController 
    public class PbxPortalRestControllerSet {

     @RequestMapping("/testMe")
     public String testMe()
     {
      return "I am alive";
     }
   }



    @SpringBootApplication
    public class PbxPortalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PbxPortalApplication.class, args);
     }
}
 Application.properties file
 server.port = 8088
```

can anyone tell what the heck is going on? I have done this tons of times before, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this refuses to work.

I try to to go to localhost:8088/testMe, and I get a 404.

Comment: Springboot application prints mapped endpoints in console during start. Can you check if you are able to see the endpoint in console?

Comment: I have give my code snippet. please follow package sutucture

Answer (score 0):

If `PbxPortalApplication` and `PbxPortalApplication` classes are in different package, you need to tell your application to scan the controller while loading up the app context.

Add the `@ComponentScan` to your `PbxPortalApplication` class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = PbxPortalRestControllerSet.class)
public class PbxPortalApplication
```

Comment: Yes, they are in the same package, I actually tried to add that line anyway just in case, but it had no effect. Either way it should not be required since they are both in the same package.

Comment: As per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html document A single `@SpringBootApplication` annotation can be used to enable those tree features, that is: `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan, @Configuration`. Hence it should not require `@ComponentScan` annotation

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was using the wrong POM entry. I was using Jersey somehow instead of the built in spring ones. For some reason even though I was using the wrong library, eclipse was telling me that my annotation entries were perfectly fine. Once i deleted the entry for Jersey everything worked

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping(value= "/getName")
    public String getName(){
        return "This is a Spring Boot Application";
    }
}
```

Main Class is simple:

```
package com.pcftest.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Can you try this once ?? And see if it works..

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/testMe" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Basically sometimes when you dont provide the request method type you get such types of errors

Comment: or you can try this :  @RequestMapping(value= "/testMe" , method = RequestMethod.GET)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are you have placed your controller different sub package than spring SpringApplication file. So Controller is not accessible from Spring main() 
Please add

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("ControllersPackege")
```

**CodeSnipet:SpringBootApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("ControllerPackege")
public class PbxPortalApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PbxPortalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**CodeSnipet:Controller**

```
@RestController 
public class PbxPortalRestControllerSet {

@RequestMapping("/testMe")
     public String testMe()
     {
      return "I am alive";
     }
}
```

**application.properties file**

```
server.port = 8088
```

**NB:**
Best way to put in same package or put controller class in sub-package