# Spring boot - configure context-path

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat9

I have configured `application.properties‬` as explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path) with :

```
server.servlet.context-path=/test
```

And in my @RestController I have a simple a simple `@RequestMapping`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

But still when sending a request to http://localhost:8080/test/products I get tomcat - 404 response.

Full code:

```
package com.siemens;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class ProductServiceController {
   private static Map<String, Product> productRepo = new HashMap<>();
   static {
      Product honey = new Product();
      honey.setId("1");
      honey.setName("Honey");
      productRepo.put(honey.getId(), honey);

      Product almond = new Product();
      almond.setId("2");
      almond.setName("Almond");
      productRepo.put(almond.getId(), almond);
   }



   @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<Object> getProduct() {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(productRepo.values(), HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>siemens</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>siemens</name>
    <description>Demo project for siemens</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

@SpringBootApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SiemensApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SiemensApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Running on tomcat 9, if there is more code or config needed please comment below, thank you.

Comment: You need to add @RequestMapping("/") on ProductServiceController

Comment: remove remove server.servlet.context-path=/test from application.properties

Comment: Please paste : @SpringBootApplication File

Comment: Please see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50010186/6734779

Comment: Add the @SpringBootApplication file.

Answer (score -1):

Any request should 'know' how to get to this controller. I would suggest trying this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("psc")
public class ProductServiceController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getProduct() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(productRepo.values(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

this way you can send a **GET** request, to the following url:
**http://localhost:8080/test/psc/products**

1. add the @RequestMapping annotation to specify the path to this class(controller)
2. get rid of the "/" on every @RequestMapping path value (just a cosmetic suggestion)

Comment: Why changing `@RestController` to `Controller`? He just need to review the `@RequestMapping`

Comment: I've encountered some issues with older versions, where (@)RequestMapping together with (@)RestController causes ambiguity as a (@)RestController should be configured implicitly by the system, and (@)RequestMapping's path is configured explicitly.
(@)Controller solves this issue.

Comment: `@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody` so there isn't any implicit system configuration.

Comment: yes, it does work properly like that. I've edited my original answer.